# 'Cannot Find Symbol' error when using a 'for' loop

Tags: java

I am a complete beginner with Java and am having trouble understanding how to pass objects around between classes and methods.  I have made some progress, however my app now fails when I try to create playing cards inside a for loop.   It works fine if I remove the loop.   Here is the first part of the class that contains the error:

```
public class Testing
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

   int Deal = 1;

   for(int Hand = 0; Hand < Deal; ++Hand)
   {
     //instantiate and derive values for Player
     Card card1 = new Card();
     card1.setSuit();  //assign card 1's suit
     card1.setValue(); //asign card 1's value

     //instantiate and derive values for Computer
     Card card2 = new Card();
     card2.setSuit();  //assign card 2's suit
     card2.setValue(); //assign card 2's suit

     //compare the two cards and make sure they are different
     cardCompare(card1,card2);
   }

   //output the two cards to the screen
   output(card1,card2);

}
```

This is the error I get:

```
Testing.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
   output(card1,card2);
          ^
  symbol:   variable card1
  location: class Testing

Testing.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
   output(card1,card2);
                ^
  symbol:   variable card2
  location: class Testing
2 errors
```

Since the code works if I remove the for loop, I'm assuming that somehow the names card1 and card2 are not visible outside the loop?  If I wanted to create ten or twenty cards, I'd want to do that in a loop, so I must be missing something about instantiating new objects and using them elsewhere in the program.

Thanks for your help.

**Update: thanks for the initial feedback.  I see now that if I move my instantiate statements outside the for loop, I could theoretically assign new values for those objects over and over again using a loop, which is all I need to complete this particular task.

I'm still curious though, is it not possible to instantiate new objects inside a loop, but still use them outside the loop?   It seems like this must be possible somehow.

```
public class Testing
   {
    public static void main(String[] args)
   {

int Deal = 1;

   //instantiate and derive values for Player
     Card card1 = new Card();

      //instantiate and derive values for Computer
     Card card2 = new Card();

   for(int Hand = 0; Hand < Deal; ++Hand)
   {
     card1.setSuit();  //assign card 1's suit
     card1.setValue(); //asign card 1's value

     card2.setSuit();  //assign card 2's suit
     card2.setValue(); //assign card 2's value

    //compare the two cards and make sure they are different
     cardCompare(card1,card2);
   }


   //output the two cards to the screen
   output(card1,card2);


}
```

Comment: My answer has the full code for what you want to do. If you need anything explained in better detail, let me know.

Answer (score 5):

The card1 and card variables are declared inside the for loop and is thus only visible inside of the loop. To use it outside of the loop, you must declare it *before* the loop. Please read up on Java *scoping rules*.

Comment: That's along the lines of what I was thinking, but if I needed 20 different cards, would I need 20 declare statements?   That seems to defeat the purpose of the loop.

Comment: @Somwhat: for 20 different cards, use either an array of Card, Card[], or perhaps better, an `ArrayList<Card>`.

Comment: Also, since I'm a complete noob, what would my declare statement look like in this case?

Comment: Declaration would be ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();

Read up the Collections chapter from any Java book or from the Oracle docs.

Comment: Sorry, my fault.  If I just wanted to declare card1 and card2 before the for loop, what would I type?  Since I want to use the variable to represent playing Card() objects, would I call it an int, String or what?  Arrays is the next chapter but I'd like to get this simple example working first.

Comment: It needs to be a Card variable, just like you're declaring it now.

Answer (score 2):

Both `card1` and `card2` are in scope of the `for` loop, not the rest of `main()`.  Move your initialization to before the `for`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as it stands, its going to keep trying to overwrite card1 and card2 since you'll both declare and initialize them "deal" times. Additionally, and more importantly, they'll be out of scope. Instead, declare it beforehand and only *initialize* them inside the loop.

What you probably want here is:

```
public class Testing
   {
    public static void main(String[] args)
   {

 int Deal = 1;

 ArrayList<Card> playerCards = new ArrayList<Card>();
 ArrayList<Card> computerCards = new ArrayList<Card>();

  //instantiate and derive values for Player
 Card card1;

 //instantiate and derive values for Computer
 Card card2;

 for(int Hand = 0; Hand < Deal; ++Hand)
 {
    card1 = new Card();
    card1.setSuit();  //assign card 1's suit
    card1.setValue(); //asign card 1's value

    card2 = new Card();
    card2.setSuit();  //assign card 2's suit
    card2.setValue(); //assign card 2's value



   //compare the two cards and make sure they are different
   cardCompare(card1,card2);

   playerCards.Add(card1);
   computerCards.Add(card2);
```

}

```
  //output the two cards to the screen

  output(card1,card2);
```

}

Haven't tested it, but it should work.

You also need to rethink your use of your Output method, too. Since you're going to have ~20 cards per person, *when* do you think you need to show them to the user? Currently, you have it outside of the for loop, so it's only going to display the LAST value assigned to each one. If you want to show them each card they're getting, put the output call inside the for loop, and maybe use Thread.Sleep() to pause the program for a half second or so so that they can see each card they get. That, or write an overload of output that accepts an ArrayList of cards, and prints all of them at the same time. Once again, if you need help with that, ask me.

By the way, im not sure what cardcompare() is really doing behind the scenes, but you probably want to make it return a bool representing whether or not they were different. something like:

```
bool areCardsDistinct = cardcompare(card1,card2);
```

That way, you can use the result to decide whether or not to get random new cards again

Comment: Yes, thanks Phillip, your solution is close to what the next stage of the assignment is about, which deals with arrays, and involves giving multiple cards to each player. Like you said cardcompare does involve a boolean relationship, though I was doing the true/false inside the method for now.
I'll think about this for a couple days over the weekend and update on Monday if it's still unclear.