# #Help. Java code, getting the marks of 5 students and displaying the students who got A using Arrays method

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, runtimeexception

I have a problem. I am tasked to write a Java program, using the array method, that receives the marks of 5 students, and then finds and displays the number of students getting A grade. The marks are (60,56,78,99,92.5). The criteria needed to get grade A is 80 marks and above.

Everything in my code went well, except for the last statement:
System.out.println("The number of students "+count);

This is my code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Q2 {

 public static void main(String [] args) {

    double[] marks = new double[6];
    int numbers = 1;

    // This is for asking input
    for (int i = 0; i < marks.length; i++,numbers++) {
        String marksString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null,
                "Enter the marks for student "+numbers+": ");

        marks[i] = Double.parseDouble(marksString);

        int count = 0;
        if(marks[i] >= 80.0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The number of students "+count); 
 }

}
```

Everything in my code went well, except for the last statement:
System.out.println("The number of students "+count);

I received an error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable
>   source code - Erroneous tree type:

Is there anyone who can explain and correct my mistakes? :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find symbol while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19044573/cannot-find-symbol-while-loop)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - what can cause this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333285/java-lang-runtimeexception-uncompilable-source-code-what-can-cause-this)

Comment: Also: ['Cannot Find Symbol' error when using a 'for' loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10454345/cannot-find-symbol-error-when-using-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrongly declared `count` inside the `for` loop. As a result, it is not accessible outside the loop (hence the compilation error), and in addition, it's overwritten to 0 in each iteration of the loop, which means it will always have a value of 0 or 1 (before exiting the loop), instead of the correct count.

Move it outside the loop:

```
double[] marks = new double[6];
int numbers = 1;
int count = 0;
// This is for asking input
for (int i = 0; i < marks.length; i++,numbers++) {
  String marksString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null,
      "Enter the marks for student "+numbers+": ");
  marks[i] = Double.parseDouble(marksString);
  if(marks[i] >= 80.0) {
    count++;
  }
}
System.out.println("The number of students who got A is " + count);
```

Comment: *"The number of students "+count* -> *"The number of students who got A: "+count*...

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Q2 {

public static void main(String [] args) {

double[] marks = new double[6];
int numbers = 1;
int count = 0;

// This is for asking input
for (int i = 0; i < marks.length; i++,numbers++) {
    String marksString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null,
            "Enter the marks for student "+numbers+": ");

    marks[i] = Double.parseDouble(marksString);

    if(marks[i] >= 80.0) {
        count++;
    }
}
System.out.println("The number of students "+count); 
}

}
```

Your mistake is that you initialize the count inside the loop, and over each iteration, the compiler assigns the value 0 to your count. Put it above the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared and initialized the **count** variable inside the loop.As a result you will unable to get access to the **count** variable outside that for loop.And each time when the loop goes on count variable will assign to 0.Those are the two errors that you have been done.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Demo {

public static void main(String [] args) {

double[] marks = new double[6];
int numbers = 1;
int count=0;
// This is for asking input
for (int i = 0; i < marks.length; i++,numbers++) {
    String marksString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null,
            "Enter the marks for student "+numbers+": ");

    marks[i] = Double.parseDouble(marksString);

    //int count = 0;
    if(marks[i] >= 80.0) {
        count++;
    }
  }
 System.out.println("The number of students "+count); 
 }

  }
```

You should declare the count variable outside the for loop.